# No .acr file when creating glossary

Tags: texlive, glossaries, texstudio

Below is a MWE. I can't get glossaries to appear in any of my documents and I think it has something to do with the way my TexStudio is configured. I'm using the most up to date TexLive and TexStudio in Linux Mint 18.

```
\documentclass   [11pt, a4paper, oneside]{book}
\usepackage[acronym, toc]{glossaries} 

\makeglossaries
\newacronym{gdp}{GDP}{guanine diphosphate}

\begin{document}
\gls{gdp}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]

\end{document}
```

Here are the PdfLaTex and Makeglossaries commands in my TexStudio configuration (I have a folder in the root directory where the output files are saved, called Misc):

```
PdfLaTex: pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode  --output-directory=./Misc %.tex
```

`Makeglossaries: makeglossaries %`

Here are my build commands:

```
Build & View: txs:///compile | txs:///index | txs:///glossary | txs:///compile | txs:///view

Default compiler: txs:///pdflatex

Default Glossary Tool: txs:///makeglossaries
```

This simply gives me a warning that says "No file .acr" and doesn't print the glossary. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output files are written to the `Misc` directory, including the files that `makeglossaries` needs (`.aux` and `.acn`). However, `makeglossaries` doesn't know that. So you must tell it in your configuration `-d Misc` in the `makeglossaries` entry. Other entries would also have to be adapted, like `makeindex`, viewer, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So I tried this, in the command for Makeglossaries: "makeglossaries -d Misc %" (without quotes) but still no glossary. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. Actually, on my system it is a bit more involved, like `sh -c "PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin/; makeglossaries -d Misc %"` What Messages do you get. You can also try Tools > Glossary and see what messages come out of it.

Comment: Ah thank you, by doing the above I was given an extremely helpful error message reminding me to pass the "nomain" option to glossaries if I was not using a main glossary (just acronyms). Once I did this, your help with setting "-d Misc" worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve this problem on my Debian system with TeXstudio by changing the "Default Compiler" entry (reachable via Options->Configure Texstudio->Build) from

```
txs:///pdflatex
```

to

```
txs:///makeglossaries | txs:///pdflatex
```

and compiling the document with the F6 shortcut afterwards. See the attached screenshot as well:

[image: Texstudio configuration]

Answer (score 0):

If you are running makeglossaries from the command line make sure that you **don't use any extension**, e.g. if your main latex file is called my_project.tex, then you need to run:

**makeglossaries my_project**

In this way, it will generate "all glossaries". From makeglossaries output:

"either omit the extension to make all the glossaries, or specify one of the glossary files, e.g. test_acronym.tex.glo, to make just that glossary."